# Language translation using yii

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am working on internationalization of a yii project, I was referring the url [Multilingual](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/294/seo-conform-multilingual-urls-language-selector-widget-i18n/)  I am getting the widget correctly on the user page, but when I click on any of the link, then I get error `404 not found`, this is the problem with all url`s. What should I do in this case

Comment: Have you defined urlManager?

Comment: As said above, did you define the new UrlManager in your config/main.php ? With the rules given for the extention.